# How can I write to json format with the table checkbox I selected by row to column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a beginner at studying frontend. I encounter some questions that I want to write JSON format with the table checkbox I selected by row to column.
It's mean here is the db column name and its column's value. Then, I want to output like (If only Column_name's td 0,2 were checked):

```json
{
  "Column_name":["0","2"],
  "Column_name_2":[]
}
```

```html
<table id="tab">
      <tr id ='tr1'>
        <td>Column_name</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" />0</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" />1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" />2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id ='tr2'>
        <td>Column_name_2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" />3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="4" />4</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" />5</td>
      </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button class="btn-disp">Display Selected IDs</button>
```

I have some search to get each element but it seems not to meet.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-disp').addEventListener('click', e => {

    const ids = [...document.getElementById('tr1')
        .querySelectorAll('td input[type="checkbox"]:checked')]
          .map(cb => cb.value); 
      console.log(`TD1: ${ids.join(', ')}`);
      
      const id2 = [...document.getElementById('tr2')
        .querySelectorAll('td input[type="checkbox"]:checked')]
          .map(cb => cb.value); 
          
      console.log(`TD2: ${id2.join(', ')}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below snippet.

```js
$('.btn-disp').click(function(){

    var Column_name = {};
    var Column_name_tmp = [];

    var Column_name_tmp = $("input[name='Column_name']:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
        }).get(); 

    Column_name['Column_name'] = Column_name_tmp;

    var Column_name_2 = {};
    var Column_name_2tmp = [];
  
    var Column_name_2tmp = $("input[name='Column_name_2']:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get(); 

    Column_name_2['Column_name_2'] = Column_name_2tmp;

    console.log(Column_name);
    console.log(Column_name_2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <tr id ='tr1'>
    <td>Column_name</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name" value="0" />0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name" value="1" />1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name" value="2" />2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id ='tr2'>
    <td>Column_name_2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name_2" value="3" />3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name_2" value="4" />4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Column_name_2" value="5" />5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button class="btn-disp">Display Selected IDs</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems can work. First I think scanning the element with each row using for loop. then note each column by row. (May have multiple rows.) But it OK. Thanks for your help!!